# What is the purpose of overriding toString?

Tags: java, tostring

Why not create a method that returns the desired information in a class instead of overriding the toString() method?

Comment: `"Why not create a method that returns the desired information in a class..."`  -- huh? What do you mean by "returns the desired information in a class"? And what is wrong with overriding `toString()`? You do know how it meshes well with `System.out.println(...)`, right?

Comment: Can't they already do that?

Comment: I suppose I don't know that it meshes well. I've read lots of posts and all I can find is... "the toString method returns a string that textually represents this object"

Comment: So you can take advantage of polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Basically because it's guaranteed to be supported on every object. `toString()` is a member of the `Object` class, and since its job is to get a string representation of the class, other code can rely on it being there. For instance, [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (the class of `System.out`) implements a `print(Object)` method that relies on it.

Answer (score 1):

A common reason that `toString` is overridden is for classes which have members that would not be obvious to the classic implementation of `toString`. In that case, it would make sense to make a custom `toString` which returns the relevant string value of the class.